# How can I post a message to my app user's wall using Graph API?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have successfully posted a message to my own wall (or logged in users), now am trying to post to a specif user wall but no luck so far, I have been authorized to the user publish_stream, offline_access, and I tried for a long time, but keep getting error messages (# 210) User not visible, the following is my code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus (function (response)
{
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var body = '12345678 ';
        FB.api ('/ SOMEONE_ID / feed', 'post', {body: body, message: body}, function (response) {
            if (! response | | response.error) {
                alert ('Error occured:' + response.error.message);
            } Else {
                alert ('Post ID:' + response.id);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

How can I do to post a message to my app users? Does not publish messages to offline users? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The application can publish to a user's feed only if they've accepted your app and you asked for permissions of `publish_stream`.  Or if they're a friend of the the user who's accepted `publish_stream`.  You cannot, for security reasons, publish to just anyone's wall.  So instead of /{anyone's id}/feed it should be /me/feed or /{one of my friend's ids}/feed.

"*How can I do to post a message to my app users?*"

You post it in your application's feed, and if they're an app user, they should see it in their feed.

"*Does not publish messages to offline users?*"

`offline_access` will give your app the ability to post to that app user's feed.  I currently use this to help user's schedule a time and date to post something.  It works wonderfully, even for posting something to a user's page wall (great for marketing purposes).